# syntax confusion: function call versus array indexing

Tags: julia

Original title: "Kronecker product in Julia"

Assume:

```
 p       = 0.7;
 PI      = [p 1-p;1-p p];
```

and:

```
 Q       = zeros(20,20);
```

In Matlab we can run:

```
A=kron(PI(j,:),Q)
```

while in Julia:

```
A=kron[PI[j,:],Q]
```

this leads to the following error:

```
MethodError: no method matching getindex(::Base.#kron, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,2})
```

How to address this and get a result similar to Matlab?

Comment: This is a typo above, otherwise the error would have been different.

Comment: Works ok with version 0.6. Which version are you using? Is this the full expression generating the error, or just part of the source line? (recheck with your source)

Comment: I use 0.5.0. Let me check... Thanks!

Comment: Most probably the typo is the `kron` function call using square brackets instead of round

Comment: Are you sure that error matches that code?  That's a getindex error, which makes it seem like you really did the equivalent of `kron[[1.0], [1.0 2.0]]` -- trying to index into the `kron` function.

Comment: There were two typos regarding the use of round instead of square brackets. The error is the original one... I will use Julia 0.6.0 and check again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two uses of `()` in your line in Matlab:

```
A=kron(PI(j,:),Q)
```

The outer () surround the arguments being passed to the `kron` function, and the inner () provide the index into PI.  In Julia (and Python, and C, and many languages) we use different symbols for these two distinct purposes.

In Julia, we use square brackets `[` and `]` for indexing, and `(` and `)` to surround function arguments.

So:

```
julia> kron(PI[1, :], Q)
40×20 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  …  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 [etc.]
```